# Mysql showing 100% ram memory usage

Tags: mysql

I have AWS EC2 m3.xlarge with 32GB memory and mysql consume all ram in 8 hours.  It's a dedicated server so there're no other processes running at the same time.

mysql Version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4-log.

Everything works well but, it increases the memory usage up to fullfil the entire system memory in about 8 hours

Why it is consuming all memory?

mysqld :

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log          = 1
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M

sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
innodb_buffer_pool_size=15G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
skip-name-resolve=1
max_connections=50
tmp_table_size=1M
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
read_rnd_buffer_size=16K
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

performance_schema = 0
show_compatibility_56 = 1

table_definition_cache = 400
table_open_cache = 400
open_files_limit = 1200

key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size = 0

innodb-read-io-threads=1
innodb-write-io-threads=1
```

Errors in /var/log/mysql/error.log are just some Aborted connections

SHOW VARIABLES

```
auto_generate_certs ON
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF
back_log    60
basedir /usr/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    0.0.0.0
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format   ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size  25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_proxy_users   OFF
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_bin
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin   mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime   0
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disabled_storage_engines    
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   200
error_count 0
event_scheduler ON
expire_logs_days    10
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-31-21-126.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_executed_compression_period    1000
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    YES
have_statement_timeout  YES
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 178
hostname    ip-172-31-21-126
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 16106127360
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_deadlock_detect  ON
innodb_default_row_format   dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_fill_factor  100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flush_sync   ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
innodb_log_checksums    ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_numa_interleave  OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   400
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_cleaners    4
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128
innodb_purge_threads    4
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  1
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_tmpdir   
innodb_undo_directory   ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_version  5.7.28
innodb_write_io_threads 1
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine    InnoDB
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
keyring_operations  ON
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename    
log_bin_index   
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password   OFF
log_error   /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_error_verbosity 3
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog    ON
log_syslog  OFF
log_syslog_facility daemon
log_syslog_include_pid  ON
log_syslog_tag  
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_timestamps  UTC
log_warnings    2
long_query_time 2.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  FILE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  16777216
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 50
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_execution_time  0
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_points_in_geometry  65536
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  BACKUP
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users   OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
ngram_token_size    2
offline_mode    OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    5000
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosesc...
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
parser_max_mem_size 18446744073709551615
performance_schema  OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size    0
performance_schema_digests_size 0
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  0
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size    0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size 0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    0
performance_schema_hosts_size   0
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 0
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   0
performance_schema_max_digest_length    0
performance_schema_max_file_classes 0
performance_schema_max_file_handles 0
performance_schema_max_file_instances   0
performance_schema_max_index_stat   0
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   0
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   0
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    0
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  0
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances    0
performance_schema_max_program_instances    0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 0
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   0
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 0
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  0
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    0
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    0
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  0
performance_schema_max_table_handles    0
performance_schema_max_table_instances  0
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  0
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   0
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 0
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   0
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    0
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   0
performance_schema_users_size   0
pid_file    /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    24
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    0
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size    8388608
rbr_exec_mode   STRICT
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    16384
relay_log   
relay_log_basename  /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-31-21-126-relay-bin
relay_log_index /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-31-21-126-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   FILE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
require_secure_transport    OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    /var/lib/mysql-files/
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 2d861aa6-0f7e-11ea-8052-0aa51c560214
session_track_gtids OFF
session_track_schema    ON
session_track_state_change  OFF
session_track_system_variables  time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info  OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys  ON
sha256_password_private_key_path    private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56   ON
show_create_table_verbosity OFF
show_old_temporals  OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   ON
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   60
slave_parallel_type DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  ca.pem
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key server-key.pem
stored_program_cache    256
super_read_only OFF
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    -03
table_definition_cache  400
table_open_cache    400
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   0
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    196608
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timestamp   1575517228.751460
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size  1048576
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
transaction_read_only   OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction    OFF
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4-log
version_comment (Ubuntu)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

```
Aborted_clients 51
Aborted_connects    0
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  25298435
Bytes_sent  140742854
Com_admin_commands  49913
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_instance  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 128
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  3017
Com_change_db   110
Com_change_master   0
Com_change_repl_filter  0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    1466
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 725
Com_delete  67
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  3621
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 725
Com_explain_other   0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  1846
Com_insert_select   2359
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 725
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  98034
Com_set_option  1910594
Com_signal  16
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   18
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 39
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  59
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_show_create_user    0
Com_shutdown    0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_group_replication_start 0
Com_group_replication_stop  0
Com_stmt_execute    725
Com_stmt_close  725
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    725
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    3
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  1888
Com_update_multi    55
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   25
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 209
Created_tmp_disk_tables 6659
Created_tmp_files   836
Created_tmp_tables  11761
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  91469
Handler_delete  169567
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   1027858
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  40373
Handler_read_key    173093268
Handler_read_last   678
Handler_read_next   262420732
Handler_read_prev   22585716
Handler_read_rnd    30732189
Handler_read_rnd_next   1791208424
Handler_rollback    289
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  1138914
Handler_write   1757020
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  Dumping of buffer pool not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191204 16:53:43
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status    
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   54082
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   886079488
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    72703
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   926396
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   2442
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  982920
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   7934
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1350831467
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    41750
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   7093253
Innodb_data_fsyncs  20639
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    821645824
Innodb_data_reads   50395
Innodb_data_writes  84001
Innodb_data_written 1629453312
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  21469
Innodb_dblwr_writes 5413
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   188154
Innodb_log_writes   4292
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    5806
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   86009344
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    3950
Innodb_pages_read   50144
Innodb_pages_written    72703
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    8728
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    335
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    1658
Innodb_row_lock_waits   26
Innodb_rows_deleted 169567
Innodb_rows_inserted    2311986
Innodb_rows_read    2000164365
Innodb_rows_updated 4330
Innodb_num_open_files   242
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   12662
Key_blocks_used 814
Key_read_requests   188758228
Key_reads   6519
Key_write_requests  41968
Key_writes  1240
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Locked_connects 0
Max_execution_time_exceeded 0
Max_execution_time_set  0
Max_execution_time_set_failed   0
Max_used_connections    51
Max_used_connections_time   2019-12-04 18:03:51
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count 0
Open_files  89
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  300
Open_tables 387
Opened_files    366163
Opened_table_definitions    3252
Opened_tables   372839
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_index_stat_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost    0
Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost 0
Performance_schema_program_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
Queries 10338744
Questions   85082
Rsa_public_key  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyto1l14iGEp4931uqqny
RX3O4OCD2WHj4no8U5Eyoov6qqJH7C8hV3fMHZUZCS+jJx0ZXCeiQc06N3XJvOZc
OG6UsHRfNeN4FH9NaxbWR/UJ9nuuvWsFZcbt6GNM5vJaO473ThOD6oRWr/da7GXP
EiXN+TmMU1ml588Rs9RosCeKz7Yhqfwb...
Select_full_join    2994
Select_full_range_join  21
Select_range    9595
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 39982
Slave_heartbeat_period  
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   
Slave_retried_transactions  
Slave_running   
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    82
Sort_merge_passes   451
Sort_range  7959
Sort_rows   30765438
Sort_scan   20648
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 38
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Ssl_cipher_list ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES1...
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    18446744073709551615
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 5
Ssl_default_timeout 7200
Ssl_finished_accepts    38
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    Nov 22 12:21:59 2029 GMT
Ssl_server_not_before   Nov 25 12:21:59 2019 GMT
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    14
Ssl_session_cache_mode  SERVER
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  128
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  18
Ssl_verify_depth    18446744073709551615
Ssl_verify_mode 5
Ssl_version TLSv1.2
Table_locks_immediate   11582
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   169305
Table_open_cache_misses 371363
Table_open_cache_overflows  370969
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   18
Threads_created 80
Threads_running 2
Uptime  28150
Uptime_since_flush_status   28150
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could help you if you would make contact.

Comment: Thank you for posting additional information requested in Dec, 19.

Comment: Do you run a lot of SQL queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA? My team mate reported a memory leak bug against MySQL 5.7.28: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97935

Comment: RAM size: 32
# cores: 8
SSD devices: no

Comment: queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA: no

Comment: skype name : xande_dys

Comment: Thank, awaiting your acceptance of my Skype invite.  Normally checked 3 x a day.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=100  # from 50 to avoid rejecting connection attempts
thread_cache_size=100  # from 0 for a more reasonable number
innodb_read_io_threads=16  # from 1 for higher performing data retrieval
innodb_write_io_threads=16  # from 1 for higher performing write operations
```

be consistent in your use of underscores rather than hyphens in my.cnf to avoid confusion.

This is the tip of the iceberg for your changes.  There are more, make contact, please.